# preview 2d array 8x8 doesn't work in c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to make a code which displays a checkerboard/chessboard. I gave every square on the checkerboard a number, so I can manually choose the position of the pieces as purpose of future programming. This is what I got:

```
#include <stdio.h>
//{",",",",",",","},
void main()
{
int board[8][8] = {
{'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'},
{'9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'},
{'17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'},
{'25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32'},
{'33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40'},
{'41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48'},
{'49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56'},
{'57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64'}
};

      /* Display the checkerboard */
printf("\n\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[0][0], board[0][1], board[0][2], board[0][3], board[0][4], board[0][5], board[0][6], board[0][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2], board[1][3], board[1][4], board[1][5], board[1][6], board[1][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[2][0], board[2][1], board[2][2], board[2][3], board[2][4], board[2][5], board[2][6], board[2][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[3][0], board[3][1], board[3][2], board[3][3], board[3][4], board[3][5], board[3][6], board[3][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[4][0], board[4][1], board[4][2], board[4][3], board[4][4], board[4][5], board[4][6], board[4][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[5][0], board[5][1], board[5][2], board[5][3], board[5][4], board[5][5], board[5][6], board[5][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[6][0], board[6][1], board[6][2], board[6][3], board[6][4], board[6][5], board[6][6], board[6][7]);
printf("---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");
printf(" %c | %c | %c| %c | %c | %c | %c | %c \n", board[7][0], board[7][1], board[7][2], board[7][3], board[7][4], board[7][5], board[7][6], board[7][7]);

}
```

This is the output:

```
 1 | 2 | 3| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 9 | 0 | 1| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 7 | 8 | 9| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 5 | 6 | 7| 8 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 2                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 3 | 4 | 5| 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 0                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 1 | 2 | 3| 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 9 | 0 | 1| 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6                                                                                                                                                        

---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---                                                                                                                                                      

 7 | 8 | 9| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

With warnings like:

```
main.c:13:37: warning: multi-character character constant[-Wmultichar]                                                                        
{'57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64'}
```

It looks like a character can't print higher then 9?! What I wanted was a simple preview of a checkerboard (with a 2d array). I tried to changed some parts in this code, but without any luck... Any ideas?

Comment: you need double quoted strings not chars, and %2s format in a loop. Seriously you cannot copy/paste lines and lines of printf like this.

Comment: Remove all the single quotes and use `"%d"` in your `printf`

Comment: `int` is not `char`. Multi-symbol character literals doesn't make any sense. Hence the compiler warning. Neither does it make any sense to have a look-up table with just adjacent numbers, you can calculate these in run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot put a string in single quoted characters. Must be a sole character.
But it has no meaning to hardcode a list of consecutive integers in strings, so:

A simple double loop with a formula is much more compact and saves a lot of copy/paste:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j;

      /* Display the checkerboard */
     printf("\n\n");
     for (i=0;i<8;i++)
     {
       for (j=0;j<8;j++)
       {
         printf("%3d ",i*8+(j+1));
       }
       printf("\n---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---\n");

   }
  }
```

result:

```
  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
  9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
 57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64
---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---
```

enhanced version with better framing (just for fun)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i,j;

   /* Display the checkerboard */
printf("\n\n\n|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n");

for (i=0;i<8;i++)
{
   printf("|");
   for (j=0;j<8;j++)
   {
      printf("%2d |",i*8+(j+1));
   }
   printf("\n|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+\n");

}
```

}

result

```
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| 9 |10 |11 |12 |13 |14 |15 |16 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|17 |18 |19 |20 |21 |22 |23 |24 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|25 |26 |27 |28 |29 |30 |31 |32 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|33 |34 |35 |36 |37 |38 |39 |40 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|41 |42 |43 |44 |45 |46 |47 |48 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|49 |50 |51 |52 |53 |54 |55 |56 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|57 |58 |59 |60 |61 |62 |63 |64 |
|---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

still not an ASCII-art mastery but better :)

Comment: Yea you're right, it makes the code more compact! And your ASCII-art skills seems fine ;P

Answer (score 1):

Replace your board definition `'xx'` => `xx`:

```
int board[8][8] = {
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8},
    ....
{57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64}
};
```

Change the `printf` formatting (`%c` => `%2d`)

```
printf(" %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d | %2d \n", board[1][0], board[1][1], board[1][2], board[1][3], board[1][4], board[1][5], board[1][6], board[1][7]);
....
```

Note:

- When you write `int foo = '0';`, you ask the compiler to store the value of character '0' in the variable `foo`.

  The value of character `'0'` is different of `0`.
- When you write `int foo = '10';`, your compiler tells you that it does not understand what you mean, because if `'0'` and `'1'` are characters, `'10'` means nothing.
- `%c` and `%d` are different in `printf`:

  - `printf("%c", foo);` will ask to print the character which code is `foo`
  - `printf("%d", foo);` will ask to print the value of `foo`
  - `printf("%c", 'a');` will ask to print the character `a`
  - `printf("%d", 'a');` will ask to print the value of character `a`

Comment: Why would you ever want to have a look-up table with nothing but constant, adjacent numbers though? Doesn't seem that these numbers will ever change, as their purpose is to enumerate squares.

Comment: Thanks, those last notes are really usefull